# javascript to send value to $_POST in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I want to do is to use a confirm box where if the user clicks OK, to delete a row from my SQL database. I have a js function I use to send the value "delete" to a php function on the same file like this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?") == true) {
            document.getElementById("delete").name = "delete";
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The button where the user will click to delete an image is this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Delete Image</button>
```

I send the value to the PHP function like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="delete" id="delete">
```

This is my PHP function:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $img_path=$_POST['ipath'];
    $imgid=$_POST['imgid'];
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
    $delete = "DELETE FROM images_info
                WHERE Image_Id = $imgid";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $delete);
    echo "Image Deleted : $imgid";
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I believe it's gotta do with the javascript

Comment: to use $_POST in php you need form with method post

Comment: You need to use `ajax` for this.

Comment: The html is inside `<form action="newsearch.php" method="post">`. However I opened and closed several `<div>`s inside this form. Will this make a difference? @DivyeshSavaliya

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, is there a simple way like this using ajax? I'm not familiar with ajax

Comment: no...its fine to have div inside form

Comment: Yeah, then the form shouldn't be the problem, right?

Comment: yes..it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: If you are using `($_POST['delete']` then any input type should have their **name attribute value as delete**.

Answer (score 6):

in your html, input name attribute is empty,

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="delete" id="delete">
```

it should be like

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="delete" id="delete">
```

`$_POST['delete']` will not be set until the name attribute is provided with the value 'delete'

Comment: the whole point of adding the javascript was to use a confirm box to ask the user to confirm if he/she wants to delete. If I wanted to delete straightaway by clicking a button, your method works

Comment: and in your php code u can use if(isset($_POST['delete'] && $_POST['delete'] == 'delete' )) ,  if you want to be sure that the data is not modified on client side before submitting the form

Comment: I think the problem here is with the javascript that send the value to the php. `name="delete"` is not what I'm looking for

Comment: You can use JavaScript to control the flow of data, but ultimately you do have to send your data from the client to the server. For `_POST` this means using the elements in your `<form>`. You can use JavaScript all you like to control the form input, but make your the final data gets to the form elements' `name` and `value` fields.

Comment: can u be more specific what is happening actually? 
i have tried to run this in fiddle the issue i m facing is, if i click yes, it sets the name = 'delete' and you can't undo that if u again click cancel in confirm dialog.
so if once clicked yes the name will be set to delete and the php code will delete the image for sure

https://jsfiddle.net/mommso8c/

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this. here is [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m4t9-acrz)

**PHP CODE**

```
  <?php
     if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
        // PERFORM YOUR DELETE QUERY HERE
        print_r($_POST);
     }
   ?>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
      <script>
      function myFunction() {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?") == true) {
         document.getElementById("delete").name = "delete";

       }else{
       return false;
       }
     }
   </script>
```

**HTML**

```
     <form method="post" action="">
         <button onclick="myFunction()">Delete Image</button>
         <input type="hidden" name="" value="delete" id="delete">
     </form>
```

Comment: how form will submit?

Comment: By clicking on Submit Button. which i have added below delete button , see html code.

Comment: so user have to click two button? first, delete image then submit? if user directly click on submit how he get alert ?

Comment: you need to add another javascript on form submit but better to use ajax instead if you want this type of validation.

Comment: @Sona, can you give me an example how to use ajax for this? I'm not familiar with ajax

Comment: @YohanBlake here is fiddle without Ajax of working code. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m4t9-acrz

Answer (score 1):

Do not use onclick="myFunction()" in the `<input>` tag. Instead, ensure:

```
<form method ="post" onsubmit="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")">
    <button name = "delete">Delete Image</button>
</form>

  <?php
 if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
     $img_path=$_POST['ipath'];
     $imgid=$_POST['imgid'];
     $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
     $delete = "DELETE FROM images_info WHERE Image_Id = $imgid";
     $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $delete);
     echo "Image Deleted : $imgid";
     mysqli_close($link);
 }
   ?>
```

Comment: Good job @Manav

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$_POST` is an associative array obtained from a form's `<input>` tags. The keys into `$_POST` are defined by the `name` attributes of an input tag, and the corresponding values in `$_POST` are defined by the `value` attribute in the same tag. Data in `$_POST` does not come from JavaScript unless you use an AJAX library like jQuery. If you want to control this data with pure JavaScript, you must directly set the attributes of your input tags.

You can keep the same JavaScript code you're using, just set the input tag's `value` attribute instead of its `name`, which should always be `delete`. Then in your PHP code, you can test the value of `$_POST['delete']` to find out if the user really wanted to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like anyone wants to answer your question. If you'd like to do this with pure js, here ya go:

```
var url = 'YOUR URL POST DESTINATION HERE';
function myFunction(elem){
    var id = elem.target.id;
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'delete=true&imgid=' + id;

    xmlHttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.send(params);

}
```

You will need to set `imgid` in your js programmatically. Execute myFunction() from your page like

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Delete Image</button>
```

As a side note, it's a REALLY bad idea to let users post to a form and modify your DB. ANYONE can make a post request and delete your DB. But I decided to give you the benefit of the doubt and answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and if it's not good to use POST to modify db data, what's the best way? Sorry I'm new

Comment: You need to be very careful when building SQL queries with user input, even if it has been sanitized. Your PHP is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. If I sent `1 OR 1=1`, it would delete your entire images_info table. I recommend [this tutorial on using PHP Data Objects](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for all this mess guys, the actual problem was that I had another form inside the form. I didn't know that forms cannot contain forms inside them. Removed the other form, and it works